Index Page Content getting jumbled by Tika for docx file
Text on Index page is getting jumbled. Page number is coming at the start of line in docx file.
While parsing the docx file. The text for index page the page number is coming at front pd the line which is making the output text as incorrect. The content of the index page looks like this.
Here page number (3) is coming at the start of the line.
